# Camera not tracing the path properly

Tags: javascript, three.js

I followed the [this](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_extrude_splines.html) example in three.js .
In the example the camera and the curve mesh are added to a object 3d .

In my case an not doing it,since i need to place the mesh exactly over a dynamically created texture .

The issue i am facing here is , the curve  made is successfully added to the scene, but the camera is not tracing the path properly.
I have copied the code  animating the splineCamera in the animate function and made some changes . Please have a look to
[my code](https://jsfiddle.net/arunjayakumar07/woLsa9j7/)

A portion of code in animate function is

```
var time = Date.now();
var looptime = 20 * 1000;
var t = (time % looptime) / looptime;
var pos = tube.parameters.path.getPointAt(t);
 pos.multiplyScalar(2);
var segments = tube.tangents.length;
 var pickt = t * segments;
 var pick = Math.floor(pickt);
 var pickNext = (pick + 1) % segments;
binormal.subVectors(tube.binormals[pickNext], tube.binormals[pick]);
binormal.multiplyScalar(pickt - pick).add(tube.binormals[pick]);
var dir = tube.parameters.path.getTangentAt(t);

 var offset = 15;

 normal.copy(binormal).cross(dir);
 pos.add(normal.clone().multiplyScalar(offset));

 splineCamera.position.copy(pos);
 var lookAt = tube.parameters.path.getPointAt((t + 30 /tube.parameters.path.getLength()) % 1).multiplyScalar(2);
 if (!lookAhead)
  lookAt.copy(pos).add(dir);
splineCamera.matrix.lookAt(splineCamera.position, lookAt, normal);
splineCamera.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix(splineCamera.matrix,splineCamera.rotation.order);
 Renderer.render(Scene, splineCamera);
```

whether am missing anything